# How to subtract a value from specific values in a column on R

Tags: r

So I am working on a data frame on a column that should say hours of sleep per night however using `difftime()` function has given values which show the number of hours sleep in negative values for some and the number of hours awake in positive values for others. I want to subtract 24 from just those who are above 0 (non negative numbers) so I have done:

```r
data$Sleep.time <- with(data = data, 
                        difftime(Bed.time, Waking.up.time, units = "hours"))

data$Sleep.time <- as.numeric(data$Sleep.time)

data$subtract <- (24)

data$Sleep.time <- if (data$Sleep.time>0) {data$Sleep.time - data$subtract}
```

So this just takes 24 away from all of the values so my values that are already negative are completely wrong. I'm not quite sure how to use the if function so this works properly any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

`if` is not vectorized i.e. it expects a logical expression with `length 1`.  The 'Sleep.time' column will have more than one element.  We may either use `ifelse` or create an index and use it to subtract and assign

```
i1 <- data$Sleep.time> 0
data$Sleep.time[i1] <- data$Sleep.time[i1] - data$subtract[i1]
```

Comment: ,@akrun, Is there a source where I can find which of the R functions are vectorized ant which are not?

Comment: @TarJae You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568392/how-do-i-know-a-function-or-an-operation-in-r-is-vectorized)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ifelse
something like this

```
data$Sleep.time <- ifelse(data$Sleep.time > 0, data$Sleep.time - 24, data$Sleep.time)
```

Syntax: ifelse(condition, if true, else) returns a vector if the condition is applied on a vector.
Hope it helps and this is vectorized, so much faster than a loop.